# Unexpected Token in Variable Declaration Javascript AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

I'm trying to create a service in Angular, but my compiler (Gulp) seems to be having problems with the variable that I define in the beginning. The exact error is `Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/*PATH*/src/app/components/demo.service.js: Unexpected token (8:8)`, and the code it's pointing at is this: `var demos = [new Demo("Example Demo", "<b>Example Demo</b>")];` with it pointing specifically at the "d" in the variable name. For context, here's the whole file:

```
import { Demo } from './interfaces/demo';

export class DemosService {
    constructor() {
        'ngInject';
    }

    var demos = [new Demo("Example Demo", "<b>Example Demo</b>")];

    addDemo(name, html) {
        this.demos.push(new Demo(name, html));
    }

    removeDemo(name) {
        this.demos.splice(this.demos.indexOf(name), 1);
    }

    updateDemo(oldName, newName, html) {
        this.demos[this.demos.indexOf(oldName)].setName(newName);
        this.demos[this.demos.indexOf(oldName)].setHtml(html);
    }

    getDemoInfo(name) {
        return [this.demos[this.demos.indexOf(name)].getName(), this.demos[this.demos.indexOf(name)].getHtml()];
    }

    getDemos() {
        return this.demos;
    }
}
```

I'm sure this is a really stupid question and that the solution is really easy, but I just can't seem to find it. Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you can't declare a variable the way you have declared demos in ES6.

Move this line :

```
 var demos = [new Demo("Example Demo", "<b>Example Demo</b>")];
```

into your constructor like this :

```
 constructor() {
        'ngInject';
      this.demos = [new Demo("Example Demo", "<b>Example Demo</b>")];
    }
```

Then when you need to access demos just make sure you call this.demos. The error is because of the way scoping works in a class in ES6.

Comment: And in doing that I can get rid of any "var demos" line outside of the constructor, correct?

Comment: I have another problem now: telling the console to log the getDemos method from another class returns "undefined". I can provide the Demo class if you'd like

Comment: Yes doing that you can get rid of any var demos outside the constructor as  variables can only be defined in a class in either the constructor or in a function. For your other issue can you  provide a sample of the code so I can see it; please.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up fixing it though. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @WubbaLubbaDubbDubb glad you got working and no problem.

Comment: This helped me. However, instead of using `this.demos`, I had to declare `this` as a variable itself like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44961696/1369235).

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the demos variable as class variable so if you change the code like this, it should be ok

```
mport { Demo } from './interfaces/demo';

export class DemosService {
constructor() {
    'ngInject';
}

private demos:any = [new Demo("Example Demo", "<b>Example Demo</b>")];

addDemo(name, html) {
    this.demos.push(new Demo(name, html));
}

removeDemo(name) {
    this.demos.splice(this.demos.indexOf(name), 1);
}

updateDemo(oldName, newName, html) {
    this.demos[this.demos.indexOf(oldName)].setName(newName);
    this.demos[this.demos.indexOf(oldName)].setHtml(html);
}

getDemoInfo(name) {
    return [this.demos[this.demos.indexOf(name)].getName(), this.demos[this.demos.indexOf(name)].getHtml()];
}

getDemos() {
    return this.demos;
}
```

}