# TypeError: "this..." is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, this, angularjs-rootscope

I define `hostService` as follows. The senario is I call first `hostService.addListener()` in the controller, then the controller may emit a message by `$rootSceop.$emit`, `hostService` is supposed to handle it.

```
app.service('hostService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {    
    this.button = function () {
        Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync("https://www.google.com", {}, function () {});
    }

    this.addListener = function () {
        $rootScope.$on("message", function (event, data) {
            this.button()
        })
    }
```

However, the problem is the above code raises an error:

```
TypeError: this.button is not a function
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: "this" scope inside  yout addListener is your globalScope and not your local.. you should copy yout scope to a var...

Comment: Every function has its own `this` context. It doesn't look to me like you're not binding `this` to anything, so in this case it's probably `window`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: this answer shows other ways to solve this ´´this´´ issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/6351322

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve this creating a self variable with `this` object, then you can call it from diferent scope:

```
app.service('hostService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {    

    var self = this

    this.button = function () {
        Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync("https://www.google.com", {}, function () {});
    }

    this.addListener = function () {
        $rootScope.$on("message", function (event, data) {
            self.button()
        })
    }
```

Comment: @4castle uuuh! my bad! thanks a lot for show to me that mistake! you are huge ;)

Comment: This helped me. However, I had to declare the function inside the constructor like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44658351/1369235) and also had to use `self.button = function()` while declaring the `button` function.